# Insert New Records Into Table Using If/Else Statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-update, sql-insert

I have two SQL Server tables where I need to add records from one table to the next.  If the unique identifier already exists in the target table, then update the record to the data coming from source table - If the unique identifier doesn't exist, then insert the entire new record into the target table.

I seem to have gotten the initial part to work where I update the records in target table but the the part where I would INSERT new records does not seem to be working.

```
if exists (
   select 1
   from SCM_Top_Up_Operational O
   join SCM_Top_Up_Rolling R ON O.String = R.string
)
begin

   update O
   set    O.Date_Added = R.Date_Added,
          O.Real_Exfact = R.Real_Exfact,
          O.Excess_Top_Up = R.Excess_Top_Up 
   from  SCM_Top_Up_Operational O 
   join  SCM_Top_Up_Rolling R on O.String = R.String
   where O.String = R.string and R.date_added > O.date_added

end

else 

begin
   insert into SCM_Top_Up_Operational (String,Date_Added,Real_Exfact,Article_ID,Excess_Top_Up,Plant)
   select String,Date_Added,Real_Exfact,Article_ID,Excess_Top_Up,Plant
   from SCM_Top_Up_Rolling
end
```

Answer (score 2):

If I followed you correctly, you should be able to solve this with a single SQL query, using [SQL Server `MERGE` syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), available since SQL Server 2008.

From the documentation:

> Runs insert, update, or delete operations on a target table from the results of a join with a source table. For example, synchronize two tables by inserting, updating, or deleting rows in one table based on differences found in the other table.

Consider the following query:

```
MERGE 
    SCM_Top_Up_Operational O 
    USING SCM_Top_Up_Rolling R ON (O.String = R.string)
WHEN MATCHED 
    THEN UPDATE SET 
        O.Date_Added    = R.Date_Added,
        O.Real_Exfact   = R.Real_Exfact,
        O.Excess_Top_Up = R.Excess_Top_Up 
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET 
    THEN INSERT (  String,   Date_Added,   Real_Exfact,   Article_ID,   Excess_Top_Up,   Plant)
         VALUES (R.String, R.Date_Added, R.Real_Exfact, R.Article_ID, R.Excess_Top_Up, R.Plant)
```

Comment: Spiffy.  I work in SQL every day, and wasn't aware that this is even a thing, because the db's I work with were rolled over from pre-2008.

Comment: I see this as being the answer but am getting  an error that I need to refine the ON clause because the "MERGE statement has tried to update or delete the same record more than once" I do indeed have two instances of the same string in the source table and that is on purpose - the idea is to have the target table updated with the most recent instance of that string record.  Is this something MERGE can handle?  I will say the source table is keyed by a record ID that is the only unique identifier on the table.  Thanks again.